# swagger code generation for spring boot page not found

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I git cloned the swagger-api/swagger-codegen project from github and tried the generated code in samples/server/petstore/springboot (mvn package and java -jar ...). The server runs but I can't access any of the apis. They always say 404 not found. Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the swagger editor too and it's the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

turned out that there is a server.contextPath parameter in application.properties of value /v1. All urls have this prefix.